# Problem in setText from func from Fragment call in MainActivity

Tags: java, android

why can't I change the TextView text, I am getting an error:

```
*java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference*
```

```
MainActivity:
CtrlFragment = new ControlFragment();
CtrlFragment.SignalStrength(100);

ControlFragment:
private void initViews(View containerView) {
txtRssi = containerView.findViewById(R.id.txt_rssi);
}

public void SignalStrength(Integer value) {
    txtRssi.setText(value+" dbi.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `txtRssi` is null, probably not getting resolved at run time. Check if you are accessing with the right `R.id.txt_rssi`.

Comment: in initViews when i do txtRssi.setText its ok, but public void - no.

Comment: What am I doing wrong? Maybe the problem is with calling a function in MainAcitivity?